# The proof of generalized mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was studying the generalized mean value theorem (or Cauchy's mean value theorem)and I studied its proof.
and when I looked for the historical context of the theorem,I read that Cauchy was the discoverer of the theorem, so my question is: What is the proof that Cauchy himself gave for his theorem?
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe better for History of Science and Mathematics stack?

Comment: do you mean the Cauchy mean value theorem? There are a couple of different generalised mean value theorems

Comment: Yeh I mean the Cauchy's mean value theorem